# Join tables using multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, left-join, sqldf

I have 2 tables in Python. I want them to join using the first 3 columns (i.e. Level1, Level2, and YearMonth). I used the following code but it would omit those rows where there was no value for YearMonth in Table 2:

```
sqldf.run("SELECT t1.Level1,t1.Level2,t1.YearMonth,t1.MemberMonths,t2.TotalER FROM Table1 AS 't1' LEFT JOIN Table2 as t2 ON t1.Level1=t2.Level1 and t1.Level2=t2.Level2 and t1.YearMonth=t2.YearMonth")
```

Please guide me a better way to achieve the desired table in Python.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the merge method in pandas follwed by a fillna.

```
df_joined = pd.merge(t1, t2, on=['Level1', 'Level2', 'YearMonth'], how='left')
df_joined['TotalER'].fillna(0, inplace=True)
```

When you perform left join, the non matching rows from the right table come as NaN. That's why you've to separately fill those NaN values as part of your post-processing step.